# Error while writing file in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writing php codeigniter from scratch 
and i am trying know write_file function in file helper
this is my controller

```
 <?php

 class Files extends CI_Controller {

    var $file;
    function Files()
    {
        $this->file = "application" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "files" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "hello.txt";
    }

    function write_file(){

        $data = "Hello World !! :)";

        write_file($this->file,$data ,'a');
        echo "writing is finishing...";
    }
 }
```

and my version is 2.1.4, befog I put 'a' it works great but after I add it 
it gives me this error

```
Call to undefined function write_file() in C:\wamp\www\test7\application\controllers\files.php
```

Comment: Where is `write_file` should be defined?

Comment: Then you should load this helper.

Comment: i loaded it in autoload

Comment: no i do, it works without the file mode 'a'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a helper function in codeigniter, you'll need to load it first:

```
$this->load->helper('file');
```

Just add this line either in the your controller's constructor function or before you use `write_file()`

Comment: sorry i forget to say, i loaded it in autoload